# What is the difference between -HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError options?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

In Oracle's [official doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABJIDID) `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` option specified with plus and minus sign. I'm just curious what do they stand for since it's not explained in official user guide

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> it’s not explained

Certainly it is. From the [page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm) you cited:

> Some command-line options use the HotSpot implementation format; that
> is, you must place the colon (:) between the -XX and the option name
> followed by a the necessary operator to indicate enabling (+) or
> disabling (-) the new hash function.

Comment: Thanks for quoting it here, since Oracle decided to move the doc page.